# Is it possible to self host a Branch.io deepView on our servers

Tags: branch.io

We would like to customize the deepView and add JS features (like a wistia video) for iOS 11 users who get the branch link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, one cannot host deep views on one's server. However you can make changes into the HTML editor provided by Branch.

To make changes, go to Dashboard -> Web to App -> Deepviews Previews -> click on three button icon for the deepview you want to edit -> Edit -> go to Editor tab.

You should be able to see something like this:

[image]

Add required JS functionality here.